# why sometimes json output is wrapped with parentheses

Tags: php, json

I just started using JSON, sometimes I am still a little in over my head.

When I retrieve data from [this link](https://getbible.net/json?passage=1samuel3:16&v=cus), there is a pair of parentheses wrapping the JSON string(or object literal):

```
({"book":[{"book_ref":"1 S","book_name":"1 Samuel","book_nr":"9","chapter_nr":"3","chapter":{"16":{"verse_nr":"16","verse":"\u4ee5 \u5229 \u547c \u5524 \u6492 \u6bcd \u8033 \u8bf4 \uff1a \u6211 \u513f \u6492 \u6bcd \u8033 \u554a \uff01 \u6492 \u6bcd \u8033 \u56de \u7b54 \u8bf4 \uff1a \u6211 \u5728 \u8fd9 \u91cc \uff01\r\n"}}}],"direction":"LTR","type":"verse","version":"cus"});
```

In my past experience, I never saw such a thing. (For example, [this link](http://67.20.67.232/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=2&Itemid=150&lang=zh-cn&format=json) outputs a JSON string that has no parentheses. )

To my surprise, it seems I can just use it as usual in jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'http://getbible.net/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: 'p=John1&v=kjv',
    jsonp: 'getbible',
    success:function(json){console.log(json)}
});
```

However, when I try to get it using PHP's `file_get_contents()` and then `json_decode()`, the parentheses seems to be in the way and `json_decode()` is returning nothing.

So what is the purpose for the parentheses? Is it related to jsonp? And is there anyway to use this kind of JSON in PHP way without writing codes to get rid of the parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a callback parameter in the url you provided for accessing the data. Because the data interchange format is jsonp. Those parenthesis  are probably added because the callback is being evaluated as an empty string.

See the example below with the url you provided.

```
https://getbible.net/json?passage=1samuel3:16&v=cus&callback=foo //foo is the callback name
```

It returns the data with the callback name foo.

```
foo({"book":[{"book_ref":"1 S","book_name":"1 Samuel","book_nr":"9","chapter_nr":"3","chapter":{"16":{"verse_nr":"16","verse":"\u4ee5 \u5229 \u547c \u5524 \u6492 \u6bcd \u8033 \u8bf4 \uff1a \u6211 \u513f \u6492 \u6bcd \u8033 \u554a \uff01 \u6492 \u6bcd \u8033 \u56de \u7b54 \u8bf4 \uff1a \u6211 \u5728 \u8fd9 \u91cc \uff01\r\n"}}}],"direction":"LTR","type":"verse","version":"cus"});
```

See the example below which shows how to access the data.

```
var url="https://getbible.net/json?passage=1samuel3:16&v=cus&";
var callbackname = "callback";
$.getJSON(url+'callback=' + callbackname, function(json){
    //loop through data
    $.each(json.book,function(i,dat){
        document.write(dat.book_ref); //print the book reference "1 S"
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here that PHP `json_encode` is "right", the value returned by the first link you posted is **not** valid JSON, but merely seems a fragment of javascript code for a variable assignment.

See in fact the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/), which clearly states that a JSON object must start with `{` and end with `}`

Comment: If you ask me I'd say it is not valid JSON too, but the point is, it is working! why?

Comment: Probably because `jQuery` tries to accept it even if invalid, while PHP correctly rejects it